# How do you check if GitLab `incoming_email` is configured on my self-hosted instance?

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way for a non-administrator to see if [`incoming_email`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/incoming_email.html#omnibus-package-installations) (or any other feature) is configured on a self-hosted GitLab instance?  I see no mention of it in the `https://<hostURL>/help/instance_configuration` page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed document on gitlab docs.

check this:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/incoming_email.html#set-it-up

I've been thru this once, so [lease comment if you have any issues.